# How to apply live photo filter in camera app

Tags: android, graphics

I am creating a new Android Photo app where I want to apply live filters and sticker on camera preview. I can't understand where to start. Please help me

I tried many libraries, but none of them are useful.

Comment: see this lib it will work for you https://github.com/nekocode/CameraFilter